# Perfect round corners on rectangular view

Tags: ios, swift

I have a rectangular view that I want "perfectly" round borders on the ends. I'm rounding the corners like so:

```
    contentView.layer.cornerRadius = 30; //arbitrary number

    contentView.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
    contentView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
```

And this is my result:

[image]

And this is the result I'm aiming for:
[image]

I'd like to determine the cornerRadius for my view to achieve rounded ends dynamically. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: You need to make the cornerRadius equal half the height.

Comment: and you need to do it when the layout is complete / changed, **not** in `viewDidLoad` / `init`.

Comment: ... e.g. in the view controller's [`viewDidLayoutSubviews`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621398-viewdidlayoutsubviews) (or, if doing this in a `UIView` subclass, in [`layoutSubviews`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622482-layoutsubviews)).

Answer (score 3):

You’re on the right way. Somewhat conventional approach to do it looks like this:

```
contentView.layer.cornerRadius = contentView.bounds.height / 2
```

Comment: can you show in a little bit more context where to put that code?

Comment: I've tried this (before posting the question, actually). I get a very funky result http://imgur.com/5HYe8Fx.png

Comment: @luk2302 This is in a custom view (subclass of UIView) in the init function. Just saw your comment on the OP. Guessing I need to wait until it's laid out

Comment: @user1282637 Override `layoutSubviews` and update the layer there.

Comment: You should do it with another setting up your view. Good place is viewDidLoad method of view controller. Don’t forget to set autolayout constraints or autoResizingMask. Your view needs to know its size. If you add it programmatically it gets to know it after adding as subview to parent view.

Comment: I wouldn’t recommend to put that code in didLayoutSubviews cause it is called several times while laying out a view.

Comment: @ArtKirillov No, do not set it in `viewDidLoad`. That's a view controller method. Let the custom view set itself up. And no one has recommended using `didLayoutSubviews` (another view controller method).

Answer (score 3):

If your "contentView" is a class that inherits from a UIView then:

```
class CustomView: UIView
{
    ...
    override func layoutSubviews()
    {
        super.layoutSubviews() //Don't want to change the default behavior of this func. Just want to add to it.
        layer.cornerRadius = bounds.height / 2
    }
    ...
}
```

If it's just a plain UIView in a UIViewController, then you can update it in the UIViewController's viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) method.